# Images not stacking correctly using jquery image rotator

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have an issue which I cannot seem to get rid.

I have an ebay listing in which the images don't seem to stack correctly.

After numerous hours of playing around I still can't seem to fix the issue, its really strange and so far the only listing which has this issue, present mozilla, firefox and chrome (don't have I.E but would guess its broken there too).

I know the problem is not ebay based as it is present in dreamweaver when loaded to a webpage.

here is a link to the listing showing the image issue:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/230969199881?var=&ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649

Thanks in advance, all help greatly appreciated.

Here is the css and html:

```
   <style type="text/css">
@charset "utf-8";
body {
font:100%/1.4;
color:#000;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: Sans-Serif, 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
ul,ol,dl {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h3,h6,p {
margin-top:0;
}
h1 {
font-size:80%;
display:inline;
color:#000;
margin:0;
}
h1,h2,h3,h6,h5 {
font-weight:100;
}
h2,h3,h6,h5{
color:#666;
}
h2 {
font-weight:bold;
color:#36b3fa;
fontfamily: Sans-Serif;
margin:0px;
}
h3 {
font-size:200%;
display:inline;
}
h4 {
font-size:90%;
color:#333;
font-weight:100;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
h5 {
color:#666;
font-size:100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
line-height: 5px;
}
p {
margin:0;
}
h6 {
font-size:100%;
}
#list {
margin-top:0;
margin-left:40px;
line-height: 15px;
}
.container {
background:#FFF;
overflow:none;
width: 1100px;
clear:left;
margin:0 auto;
}
.imagecontainer {
float:left;
width:550px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.header-logo {
width: 1100px;
height: auto;
}
.footer-logo {
width:200px;
float:right;
}
.copy {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
width: 50%;
margin: 30 auto;
} 
.clear {
clear:both;
}
a:hover,a:active,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
color:#333;
}
.deliverydetails,.paymentdetails,.productdescription,.feedback,.aboutus,.termsandconditions {
width:380px;
height:auto;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
padding:15px 30px 30px 30px;
border:2px solid #666;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
#footer {
float:left;
width:1100px;
font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;
clear:left;
background-color:#36b3fa; 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
height:58px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
#footer .footerText {
float:left;
width:420px;
color:white;
margin-top:16px;
margin-left:10px;
}
#footer .footerText a {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
#footer .footerText a:hover {
color:white;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.rightbox {
float:right;
width:444px;
margin-left:80px;
}
#wrapper {
width: 600px;
}
#wrapper .images {
padding:20px 0px;
text-align:center;
}
#productImages .tab {
float:left;
width:355px;
border:none;
}
#productImages-nav {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 363px; 
padding:0px;
}
#productImages-nav li {
float:left;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#productImages-nav li img {
border:1px solid #ccc;
margin:0;
opacity:0.5;
}
#productImages-nav li img:hover {
border: 1px solid #333;
opacity:0.9;
}
#productImages-nav a.active img {
opacity:0.9;
border:1px solid #36b3fa;
}
#preview {
background:#FFF;
border:1px solid #36b3fa;
padding:5px;
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
margin-top:-25px;
display:none;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 12px #666;
}
#preview img {
width:400px;
}



 <div class="imagecontainer">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "htt";var gz = "p://";
var hz = ".co.uk";
var fz0 = "sweetvision"+hz+"/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+gz+fz0+">");
document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");
-->
</script>    
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "htt";var gz = "p://";
var hz = ".co.uk";
var fz0 = "sweetvision"+hz+"/js/yetii-min.js";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+gz+fz0+">");
document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");
-->
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "htt";var gz = "p://";
var hz = ".co.uk";
var fz0 = "sweetvision"+hz+"/js/zoomer.js";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+gz+fz0+">");
document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");
-->
</script>  
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="images">
<div id="productImages">
<div id="image1" class="tab" style="display:block">
<a class="preview" name="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers.jpg">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers.jpg" width="250" height=""/>
</a>
</div>
<div id="image2" class="tab" style="display:none">
<a class="preview" name="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers2.jpg">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers2.jpg" width="250" height=""/>
</a>
</div>
<div id="image3" class="tab" style="display:none">
<a class="preview" name="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers3.jpg">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers3.jpg" width="250" height=""/>
</a>
</div>
<div id="image4" class="tab" style="display:none">
<a class="preview" name="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers4.jpg">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers4.jpg" width="250" height=""/>
</a>
</div>
<!---smaller images---->
<ul id="productImages-nav">
<li>
<a href="#image1">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers.jpg" width="100" height="" alt="jacket"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#image2">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers2.jpg" width="100" height="" alt="jacket"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#image3">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers3.jpg" width="100" height="" alt="jacket"/>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#image4">
<img src="http://sweetvision.co.uk/ebayimages/MWT/worktrousers4.jpg" width="100" height="" alt="jacket"/>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var tabber1 = new Yetii({
                    id: 'productImages',
interval:5
                    });
                    </script>

</div> <!--end productImages --->
</div> <!--- end .imgaes --->
</div> <!---end wrapper div --->       






    </div> <!---end imagecontainer---->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your productImages-nav ul a fixed width of say, 150px and then float the li's inside it to the right they will all align properly.

Not sure if this is the best way, but it does the trick.

```
#productImages-nav {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 363px; 
  padding:0px;
  width:150px;
}
#productImages-nav li {
  float:right;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I think I have worked out the issue with stacking. I believe its because I did not set a height on the images and therefore the last image in the list was being left out of the party.